# how do I remove rows that contains an element of a column in another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with rows I do not want to include in the final data frame. But I do not know how to exclude them. I tried some stuff but it didn't work and I couldn't find a fitting answer on the web.

```
first_filtered_list<- data%>%filter(Name == old_name & NUMBER_OF_LOCATIONS != PREVIEW_NUM)
```

This list contains all rows I want to exclude from the data. I can't change it to `first_filtered_list<- data%>%filter(Name == old_name & NUMBER_OF_LOCATIONS == PREVIEW_NUM)`
because the data has hundreds of duplicate names. I would like to exclude all rows whose `Name` is in the `first_filtered_list$Name`

Comment: Can you provide a small set of your data?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You can use `anti_join`, as drmariod suggested, or simply negate your condition. If `filter(Name == old_name & NUMBER_OF_LOCATIONS != PREVIEW_NUM)` keeps only all rows you want to remove, then `filter(!(Name == old_name & NUMBER_OF_LOCATIONS != PREVIEW_NUM))` removes them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `anti_join` on the columns you want to filter?

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=letters[1:5], c=runif(5))
df_to_filter <- df1[c(1,3,5),]
df1 %>% anti_join(df_to_filter, by=c('a','b'))
```

But why don't you directly filter your data?